# I am trying to solve 0/1 Knapsack problem, but I am getting output as many zeroes

Tags: python, data-structures, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Below is the code given for 0/1 knapsack problem, where i am getting most zeroes in my output table. How can I understand why this problem is happening and how to solve this issue?

```
    item = 4
    profit = [1, 2, 4, 5]
    weight = [5, 4, 8, 6]
    bag = 5
    import numpy as np
    table=np.zeros([item,bag]) 

for j in range(bag):
    for i in range(len(weight)):
        if i==0 or j==0 :continue 

        elif j< weight[i]:
            table[i][j] = table[i-1][j]
            #print(i,j)
        else: 
            table[i][j] =max((profit[i]+table[i-1][j-weight[i]]),
            (table[i-1][j]))
print(table)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  2.]]
```